# How to increment div ids in JS dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to understand how can I increment div ids  in JS dynamically.

I am adding similar DIVs everytime, but they are different elements.

Let's consider this quick example to clarify what I am trying to understand;

```
<div class="test" id="b1">
    One
</div>


<div class="test" id="b2">
    Two 
</div>

<div class="test" id="b3">
    Three
</div>

<div class="test" id="b4">
    Four
</div>
```

You can notice that there is a loop inside this script, they are all inherit from th same div, but they are noted by different IDs.

```
$('#b1').click(function() {
    alert('I am first button');
});

$('#b2').click(function() {
    alert('I am second button');
});

$('#b3').click(function() {
    alert('I am third button');
});


$('#4').click(function() {
    alert('I am fourth button');
});
```

I am adding more than 100 DIv of the same DIv; but I need to annotate them differently, so I can apply effect when I click on every div.

What do I need to understand in order to do that ?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/sL8nbx1w/2/

**UPDATE**

Some people got me wrong, what I am trying to do is generating the div as well as the

```
<div class="test" id="HOW_CAN_I_Make_VARIABLES">
    One <span class="alertmsg">custom message for this button + HOW_CAN_I_Make_VARIABLES</span>
</div>
```

In a way that I can do something like

```
# for every variable I have  
$('.HOW_CAN_I_Make_VARIABLES').click(function() {
    alert('I am button #' + HOW_CAN_I_Make_VARIABLES_Index);
});
```

Comment: This? http://jsfiddle.net/9xwosh7g/

Comment: Blex, answer it.  You nailed it.

Comment: You can put the content of the alert in the div itself. That way you can have completely different alert messages and no need for ids.. http://jsfiddle.net/nbjgr5zh/

Comment: @blex You should probably remove the ids in your fiddle, to make it clear that they aren't necessary

Comment: Bonus challenge: generate all the `<div>` elements, too.

Comment: Here with removal of ids too and custom messages for each: http://jsfiddle.net/nbjgr5zh/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="container">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function(){
    var i=0;
    $('#container').find('div').each(function(){
        var temp='b'+i;
        $(this).attr('id',temp);
        ++i;
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. To add new container, what should I do in this case ?

Comment: To inert new container, what should I do in this case ?

Comment: as in the <div id="container"></div> ?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach event by CSS class and use `event.target.id` to get id of clicked element:

```
$('div.test').click(function(event) {
    alert('I am  button with id: '+event.currentTarget.id);
});
```

Also you can get all elements using `each` function and change their properties like:

```
$('.test').each(function (index) {
    alert("iterating element "+$(this).attr(id));
}
```

Comment: `event.target.id` == `this.id` ;) And you need quotes here: `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: This won't work if user clicks on some element inside `.test` div. `event.target` points to clicked element. It's safer to use `event.currentTarget`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vpzpxzx0/

```
// method 1
$('.test').click(function() {
    alert('I am ' + $(this).text().trim());
});

// method 2 (advanced js usage)
for(var i=1; i <= 4; i++) {
    (function(){
        var myId = i;
        $('#b' + i).click(function() {
            alert('I am ' + myId);
        });
    })();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an each() function instead of giving id's. Remove the current id's and let the function create them for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/austinthedeveloper/sL8nbx1w/3/

```
$('.test').each(function (index) {
    var value = index + 1;
    $(this).attr('id', 'b' + value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.test').click(function() {
    alert('I am button #' + ($(this).index() + 1));
});
```

[JS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/55yop702/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding what others have posted - a bit more flexibility. Each button knows the message it is going to alert (based on blex's code: http://jsfiddle.net/nbjgr5zh/3/):

```
<div class="test">
    One <span class="alertmsg">custom message for this button 1</span>
</div>


<div class="test">
    Two <span class="alertmsg">custom message for this button 2</span>
</div>

<div class="test">
    Three <span class="alertmsg">custom message for this button 3</span>
</div>
```

---

```
$('.test').click(function() {
alert('alert from button #' + ($(this).index() + 1)+ ': '+$(this).find(".alertmsg").text());
});
```

---

```
.test {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.test > .alertmsg {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a data attribute to the div:

```
<div class="div-clickable" id="div1" data-id="1"></div>
```

And on your js:

```
$('.div-clickable').click(function(e){

    var divclicked = $(this).attr("data-id");

    alert("I am div" + divclicked);

})
```